# Dynamically Generating Tables from AdobeAnalytics API within Power BI Desktop - Power Query (M)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, adobe-analytics, m, powerbi-datasource

Hello Power Query (M) and Power BI Gurus!

I'm trying to use 3 Lists within Power BI Desktop as my Parameters to create tables using the AdobeAnalytics Connector (API) (See Below for the generated Power Query Code). The AdobeAnalytics Connector only allows for the use of Segments stacked on top of each other (For those that are not familiar with AdobeAnalytics think of a segment as a filter).  So my only option (that I see thus far) is to iterate through all possible combinations of the 3 lists to generate all of the calls (i.e. trying to a Nested Loop that creates all of these tables for me and then combines them to one table).

Data Components:

- 3 Lists of values to use as my Nested Parameters for each call

  - Programs (1 Column)

    - A
    - B
    - C
  - Regions (1 Column)

    - A1
    - B2
    - C3
  - MarketingChannels (1 Column)

    - A11
    - B22
    - C33
- Power BI Desktop - Power Query AdobeAnalytics API connection

### Required Steps

**1.** Create a table for every combination of the Values within the 3 Lists e.g.:

- **Table 1** would use the following parameters:

  - (#Programs[A], #Regions[A1], #MarketingChannels[A11])
- **Table 2** would use the following parameters:

  - (#Programs[A], #Regions[A1], #MarketingChannels[B22])
- **Continue until all possible combinations are completed**

**2.** Once all of the tables have been created I need to combine them

**The below code snippet would be an example of Table 1, 
(note the line that starts with "{Cube.ApplyParameter, "Segment","as that is where the Lists above would be used as parameters)**

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!!!

```
let
    Source = AdobeAnalytics.Cubes(),
    invitrogenprod = Source{[Id="invitrogenprod"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(invitrogenprod,
        {
            {Cube.ApplyParameter, "DateRange", {#date(2018, 3, 21), #date(2018, 3, 21)}},



            {Cube.ApplyParameter, "Segment", {{"#Programs[A]", "#Regions[A1]", "#MarketingChannels[A11]"}}},





            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "DateGranularity", {"year", "month", "day"}, {"Date Granularity.Level 1: Year", "Date Granularity.Level 2: Month", "Date Granularity.Level 3: Day"}},
            {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Engaged Visits", "cm300001617_5a84e003de3c977de97c39d2"},
            {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Engaged Visits (PDP)", "cm300001617_5a58160e8f0c657d68a6e404"},
            {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Visits w/ Cart Activity", "cm300001617_5a50160c4ecbca5712928ab6"}
        })
in
    #"Added Items"
```